# So I'm trying to sort a list of a few distinct item into an inventory slot list that ALLOWS stacking and only 1 item sprite per slot with a count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collections, game-development

I've accomplished this temporarily by using a bunch of lists to sort them into first but I know this can be done with a nested for loop.

TIA
[image]

```
 public void AddToInventory(List<FoodResource> food)
{
    for (int s = 0; s < slots.Length; s++)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < food.Count; f++)
        {

        }
    }

}
public class UISlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FoodResource item;
    public Image slotImage;
    public Sprite icon;
    public Text itemCount;
}
public class FoodResource : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FoodResourceType foodType;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public float resourceValue;
    public string uniqueName;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're passing in a list of food items which may or may not already have instances assigned to a UISlot, you're going to be better off making the food loop your outer loop.  That way it will look at a food, then look at all slots for a matching food type and insert it if present, then move onto the next food. For example:

```
for (int f = 0; f < foods.Count; f++) {
    bool wasInserted = false;
    for (int s = 0; s < slots.Length; s++) {
        if (slots[s].item != null && slots[s].item.foodType == foods[f].foodType) 
        {
            // Increase the number in your itemCount Text
            wasInserted = true;
            break; // It's inserted so move on to the next food item
        }            ​
   ​}

   // If the food wasn't inserted into any slot, find the first empty slot and insert it
   ​if  (!wasInserted) {
       for (int s = 0; s < slots.Length; s++) {
           if (slots[s].item == null) {
               // Add the food to the inventory slot
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The above assumes that your slots and your food are all instantiated.

There is a simpler way to do this using Linq which would probably be faster.  Something along the lines of:

```
using System.Linq;
/*
   other stuff
*/
List<UISlot> slotsList = slots.ToList();
for (FoodResource foodResource in food) {
    UISlot selectedSlot = slotsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.item != null && s.item.foodType == foodResource.foodType);
    if (selectedSlot != null) {
        // Increment the itemCount
    } else {
        selectedSlot = slotsList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.item == null);
        // Add item to empty slot
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines anyway.

Without knowing how/when you've instantiated items, I think this should get fairly close to what you need.

Comment: The issue currently is that the slot IS already instantiated but the slot.item is not. So it doesn't pass the if slot != null check

Comment: Unity specific you should use the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) instead of `== null`/`!= null` checks .. so instead of e.g. `s => s.item != null` simply do `s => s.item`